# ssh to raspberry pi with dynamic ip address

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a raspberry pi 3 and its connected to router by LAN connection,I can make SSH connection to it when I'm connected to that router, Is there any way that I can make SSH connection to it from every where?

Where should I start? What tools do I need and how would I configure them?

*I'm really amateur in raspberry pi and network too, hope don't get down vote for silly question*

Comment: To make this work for one Pi on your network, you will need to enable port forwarding on your router and use the router's public IP address. Search for those terms and you can find a lot of information both here and else where.  Nothing about this is specific to Raspberry Pi though, so don't restrict your search to Pi. Also be aware that port forwarding increases your chances of being hacked and your ENTIRE network becoming vulnerable, not just the one Pi.  So do some reading before you try it out.

Comment: check out this link: http://www.raspberryanywhere.com/ Perhaps it can be of some help.
I'v been using the service from several weeks and it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not exposing your ssh connection to the internet as you may end up wanting to use more services from the device outside of your home lan and this could end up with you opening up multiple ports.

Instead I recommend that you install openvpn and connect through that then you ssh as if you are on your lan, and access any other devices on your lan.

This guide is the most comprehensive as I found some of the rpi specific ones had pieces missing.

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

You should be able to use the default configuration files for both the client and the server. to get the functionality of accessing the other machines on your lan you will need to add the following to your `server.conf` file `push "route 10.66.0.0 255.255.255.0"`